# Show Interstitial more than once Admob at Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, admob, cordova-admob

I have developed cross platform application using Ionic 1 framework,
for the admob I have used `cordova-admob-pro` plugin.

https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro

For the Interstitial showing, used following code portion. When I open up a page, an Interstitial is displayed for a while. 
Upto now Every thing is fine.

The problem is when I have attempted second and more times ,Interstitial is not displayed any more until I have killed an application then open it again.

Same problem is seen at both platform Android and IOS.

**What should I do?**

I have any problem with another banner at the top of the screen, it keeps displayed during application life cycle.

```
// preppare and load ad resource in background, e.g. at begining of game level
if(AdMob) AdMob.prepareInterstitial( {adId:admobid.interstitial, autoShow:false} );

// show the interstitial later, e.g. at end of game level
if(AdMob) AdMob.showInterstitial();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time before you call showInterstitial(), you must call prepareInterstitial() to load ad resource from server, and expect a onAdLoaded event.

In your code, you call showInterstitial() only once when init, which is not enough.

https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/issues/568